How to keep canvas in bounds?
I have been struggling with an issue for a few days now. I have an editor made with Canvas, and I need to add ruler support and responsiveness. To achieve this, I made the canvas responsive, and it zooms out when the window is resized. However, my canvas has panning and zooming enabled, and when the maximum zoom-out is set to 20%, you can zoom in and pan from left to right.
The issue arises with my keepCanvasInBounds function, which handles the panning bounds incorrectly when I zoom in. If the initial zoom-out is below 100%, the canvas won't pan all the way from left to right. Specifically, when zoomed in, the panning stops before reaching the far-left (30cm on the ruler), which is the expected behavior.
Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:
Access the link.
Zoom in and try to pan from left to right.
The expected outcome is that you should be able to pan all the way to the left (30cm on the ruler), but it stops prematurely. Can anyone help me out with this? Here is a link to a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/9969p6

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
